# jax: sample many observations from random.choice with replacement between them

Tags: jax

I'd like to pick two indices out of an array. These indices must not be the same.
One such sample can be obtained with:

```
random.choice(next(key), num_items, (2,), replace=False)
```

For performance reasons, I'd like to batch the sampling:

```
num_samples = 100
samples = random.choice(next(key), num_items, (num_samples, 2), replace=False)
```

This doesn't work because of `replace=False`. It raises the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

For each new sample, I'd like to have `replace=True`. Within one sample, I'd like to have `replace=False`.
Is there a way to do this?

The `next(key)` in my random sampling is syntactic sugar. I'm using this snippet for convenience:

```
def reset_key(seed=42):
    key = random.PRNGKey(seed)
    while True:
        key, subkey = random.split(key)
        yield subkey
        
key = reset_key()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using [`jax.vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.vmap.html#jax.vmap) to map across individual samples. For example:

```python
from jax import random, vmap

def sample_two(key, num_items):
  return random.choice(key , num_items, (2,), replace=False)

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
num_samples = 10
num_items = 5

key_array = random.split(key, num_samples)
print(vmap(sample_two, in_axes=(0, None))(key_array, num_items))
# [[2 0]
#  [1 4]
#  [2 1]
#  [3 4]
#  [4 2]
#  [2 0]
#  [1 3]
#  [2 1]
#  [1 0]
#  [2 4]]
```

For more information on `jax.vmap`, see [Automatic Vectorization in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/03-vectorization.html).

Comment: Hi Jake; Are there any performance implications of splitting the keys up front, as compared to sampling an extra dimension with a single key? Obviously random state needs to be incremented internally in the latter case as well, and in theory JAX could optimize away the instantiation of the key_array under jitting; but does it? I guess 'benchmark it' should give the real answer; but curious as to the current state of the JAX compiler.